# Is it possible to normalize an un-normalized cross-correlation vector after computation

Tags: cross-correlation, normalization

I have a C++ code that computes cross-correlation for a given 2 vectors as input. It doesn't have an implicit normalization or normalized implementation of cross-correlation. But I would prefer a noramlized output. I referred the Wikipedia article on [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) and it states the following formula to get a normalized cross-correlation:

[image: Normalized Cross-Correlation]

I was wondering:

1. since $\sigma_f$ and $\sigma_t$ and are going to be a constant scalar for any given vectors, can I just multiply
   $$
   \frac{1}{n * \sigma_f * \sigma_t}
   $$

   to the cross-correlation vector and obtain a normalized cross-correlation vector? Please correct me if I'm wrong here and suggest a way to do it if it's possible.
2. what can be done if both input vectors are not of the same size? Is zero-padding the shorter vector the only option? Or can the above factor be modified to accomodate both the lengths?